Why does the LC tank behave differently when I change the input impedance of my oscilloscope to 50 ohms?
Edited
I built a LC tank with two series capacitors (0.91 nF of total capacitance), a parallel inductor (33 µH) and a natural frequency of about 918 kHz. When I feed a signal to the tank and measure the frequency response with my oscilloscope input impedance set at 1 MΩ, I get the following response:

You can clearly see a voltage spiked at the natural frequency, which is to be expected; however, when I change the input impedance of my oscilloscope from 1 MΩ to 50 Ω I get an opposite response. 
As you can see the signal seems to be attenuated as it moves closer to the natural frequency and this seems to be the case regardless of whether the output impedance of the signal source is 50 Ω or 1 MΩ. In the graph above, I’m using a 50 Ω output impedance signal source to match the 50 Ω input impedance of the scope. At the natural frequency, both the inductive and capacitive reactance should cancel each other out leaving only the input and the output impedance of the signal source and scope respectively; hence, there should be maximum power transfer. As you can see that is not what I see in this graph. Any insights as to what is happening here?
I added the circuit diagram below for reference. the 50 Ω is the output impedance of the signal source, followed by the LC tank and the 50 Ω input impedance of the oscilloscope. My understanding is that at the natural frequency the LC tank should be behave almost like a short circuit since the reactance should cancel each other out?


What do you believe the purpose of changing the input impedance is, exactly?

Be precise in your question - give the values for each C and L.  It will be quite easy for and experienced EE to help you with the answer.

Please update your question to add the C and L values and your source impedance so a precise answer can be given.
However, the difference in the two plots is due to the fact that your inductor is in parallel with your oscilloscope's input impedance.
In the Rin=1Megohm case, the inductor's impedance is <<1Mohm over the frequency range , and the result is close to what you expect?
In the Rin=50ohm case, the inductor's impedance is >> 50ohms over the frequency range.  In this case the circuit can be approximated by your C in parallel with 50ohm.  The shape of this curve is the same as an impedance curve for a capacitor - an actual capacitor with ESR and ESL.  The actual voltage values should be explained by your source impedance and the 50ohm Rin of the scope.

Thanks a lot for your help. the value of the total capacitance and inductance are 0.91nF and 33uH respectively; however, my inductor is in series with the input impedance of the  oscilloscope, not in parallel. I added a circuit diagram for your reference. at the natural frequency, the reactance of the LC tank should cancel each other out. At the point the tank should behave almost like a short circuit leaving only resistive losses. That is why I'm confused.

There two shunt C's around a series inductor to create this type of parallel then series notch forward response.  It is similar to all parallel crystal responses with load caps which expect a high resistance load ratio and not 50 Ohms for a sharp peak gain.
All these characteristics of  fp, fs , Q BW are well defined by impedance ratios are well defined on Wiki and GPT if you want a full page on this.
Let's look at charge moving in slow motion in the time domain.  Yes the LC tank is a series loop to itself and the current will peak at V/Zo in the steady state.  But the Voltage source if converted to a Norton Current source looks like the tank is severely loaded by a low series R and the peak current will be Ip(t)=Vp(t)/(Zo+Rs). If the initial condition is 0V at t=0, the generator can see a time-varying impedance (Zo(t) in the tank circuit.
Is(t)= V(t)/(Rs+Zo(t))  Zo is initially a short circuit at t=0 but when the Cap has charged up to Vs we expect the Inductor will share the cap current as a short circuit small loop but now the voltage can match the input if the generator runs near the resonant frequency. You can even tune f to null the series R current while the tank resonates with the stored energy, E oscillating back and forth between L & C.  If you compute the \$E= 1/2 LI^2=1/2CV^2\$, in either component it will match the total energy lost in the series R, \$E=V^2/R=I^2R\$ to charge up that stored energy no matter what value of R is used.  The energy supplied by Vs will also be the same as what is stored in C or transferred to L when Vc(t)=0 and this is stored reactive energy. (lossless energy since ideal reactance).
In short (no pun intended) Voltage gain is done in a series resonance in series with the low R generator or in parallel driven by a current source like a pumped open collector.

Other info: For the advanced Eng who understands the CLC resonance of a piezo device, MEMs or a crystal, with a Q= 10,000 how much voltage do you expect inside the lattice of the series LC loop? Is this why the power to Xtals is often specified 50 uW max as the quartz lattice which has very high breakdown voltage /mm and so how many xx kV inside the Xtal will cause an arc and damage the Xtal at the crystal lattice parallel resonant structure?
Here is your simulation.
You can press reset, toggle the switch, change f or even change anything else.  Note this value of Zo ~ 316 has the same peak current as the dummy 316 load resistor I added to the voltage source (R=0).
You cannot put caps in parallel as this could imply infinite current so all real caps in parallel must have ESR added to a simulation if you want better realism. If there is a convergence error, that means the sample rate is too slow and violates the Nyquist theorem. (This means you need much more than > 2 samples per cycle to preserve accuracy but only 2 samples /cycle to detect f at some random phase.

Thanks for your help. Can you please elaborate more? I'm aware of the concept of impedance ratio, but that doesn't answer my question. the capacitors are in parallel with the inductor, but both the capacitors and inductors are in series with the input impedance of the scope. I added a circuit diagram for reference. When the frequency reaches the natural frequency of the tank, the LC tank should behave almost like a short circuit leaving only the output impedance of the signal source and the input impedance of the scope, which are both 50 ohms. Am I missing something?

see how current flows when "in sync" with the source V.  is it out of phase or in phase with voltage?  || = 180 deg, series = 0

https://tinyurl.com/28dlao44 sim series and high Z series open sw. https://tinyurl.com/29shc459  change sim speed, repeat sw.

In an ideal case with a 1 Mohm load (ideal oscilloscope input impedance) you'll get nearly 0 dB gain. That is due to the impedance of the generator and the LC circuit being much lower than the 1 Mohm load of the oscilloscope. Not a useful circuit.
You don't have an ideal case since the load (oscilloscope and cabling) is now complex, that is, the impedance of the oscilloscope input plus the cabling is frequency dependent (the real part of the oscilloscope impedance changes with frequency). In the simulation below, I chose some arbitrary values, 100 kohms for the real part of the impedance and 50 pF for cable and input capacitance of the oscilloscope. I also added 10 ohms of series resistance for the inductors (part of the inductor model). This has the general shape of your plots.

In the future, plot the gain in dB and use a log scale for the frequency. This type of plot (Bode plot) is much easier for experienced practitioners to understand.
